# Socket programming PrintWriter does not produce output

Tags: java, sockets

My server code is as follow:

```
writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
writer.flush();
writer.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");                           
writer.print("Content-Length: " + len + "\r\n");
writer.print("Content-Type: "+"application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8"+"\r\n\r\n");
writer.print(response);
writer.close();
```

The variable response is SOAP+XML. I am adding the HTTP headers needed to send it over and it works in some cases but in most cases my client(SOAPUI) just waits for the response which doesn't get produced. When I close the client I don't see any error on the server side.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Socket.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29):

"...Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket....".

Closing the PrintWriter will close the OutputStream which in turn will close the socket. Just flush the PrintWriter, don't close it.